# Как вызвать триггер по ссылке JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование

День добрый!
Как вызвать событие по ссылке, чтобы можно было выполнить функцию.
Задача: Вызвать функцию, провести валидацию, вызвать другую функцию, провести валидацию и вызвать функцию по триггеру, если всё ОК.

Сейчас есть код:

```
$("#target").on('myEvent', function(e){
//callback функция, которую нужно выполнить по триггеру
alert(1);
});

var thisEl = '';
$("#target").on('click', function(e){
//выводим форму валидатора
thisEl = this; //передаём элемент по ссылке
});

$("#target button").on('click', function(e){
//проводим валидацию, если всё ОК, то...
$(thisEl).trigger('myEvent');
});
```

Видимая проблема в том, что thisEl на последнем этапе загружен, но триггер не выполняется.
Возможно я что-то делаю не так и эту задачу стоит решить иначе. Если да, прошу подсказать решение.

Comment: зачем вы юзаете этот `thisEl` если можно использовать `$("#target")` ?

Comment: Ибо этого требует задача (как я её вижу). Нужно перед выполнением функции N показать форму с каптчей, если она введена верно (Ajax-проверка) то вызвать функцию N